# Most efficient way to generate 5.0 and 13.25 volts out of 2xAA

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

Working on an instrumentation device for some friends' lab. The MCU and most of the electronics require 5V @ ~15 mA, and 13.25 volts need to be fed to one side of a differential unity-gain opamp. The requirement is to measure a lead-acid battery's voltage very precisely, and a LT1990 is used to shift the voltage from 12-13V to 0-1V to be read by a precise ADC.

The implication is that the 13.25 V reference voltage needs to be very clean, but it doesn't need a lot of current (basically none, as this is an op-amp).

The device box can accommodate either a 9V or 2xAA batteries; I've chosen AAs, as they have better energy density. My current power-supply setup is as follows:

```
                           +-> LDO -> 5V
                           |
AAs -> Polulu 791 -> 8.4V -+
                           |
                           +-> TC7660 charge pump -> 16.8V -> LM317 -> 13.25V
```

I used the Polulu 791 step-up regulator during prototyping for ease of development. As you can imagine, the current setup is awfully inefficient; the switcher inside the polulu has some 44% efficiency at low currents and high voltages. With the current loads, the batteries are drained at 100+ mA

Is there a better way to do this? General redesign is okay (but I want to keep the 2xAAs)?

Comment: No offense intended, but that's an extraordinarily silly way to measure a 12V battery. Divide it down then subtract your reference voltage. The load can be made negligible (1M or higher). Then you get rid of the 13.25V supply, and you only need to convert 2~3.5V to 5V with a tiny boost regulator.

Comment: Of course, that would have been easier, but you lose 1-2 bits of ADC precision, unless you rescale the difference after the opamp. I was also a little worried about whether the resistors wouldn't drift with age or temperature...

Comment: The resistors that set your 12V or whatever voltage you're subtracting will have exactly the same sensitivity, and you've got the additional error source of a second reference and the matching of the resistors in the LT1990. The only thing that is better is the sensitivity to the offset voltage of the op-amp and it's not hard to find op-amps 10x or 100x better than the LT1990 in terms of input-referred offset voltage and drift.